# Rebuild ASP.NET Web Application via code

Tags: c#, asp.net

Currently I force ASP.NET to rebuild a web application by changing the web.config. However, I would prefer to do it via C# code (including clearing cache etc). How could I go about doing this.

Comment: Dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080255/how-do-i-force-asp-net-to-invalid-and-thus-reload-the-current-application-insta

Comment: Thanks, missed that one. Used the code by Rick Stahl (http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/5688.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used code from '[Recycling an ASP.NET Application from within](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/5688.aspx)' to do this via code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about live, on a web server?  You could stop/start the application within IIS, and probably via a PowerShell or WMI script.